# How to add special span to addDisplayGroup fieldset

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, zend-form

What should I modify in this piece of code.

```
$this->addDisplayGroup($groupInputs, 'group_'.$i, 
                    array('attribs'=>array('class'=>'fieldset_group')));
```

to add in fieldset new html tag like:

```
<span class="delete_fieldset" onclick="foo()">[X]</span>
```

Or if its possible:

```
 <span class="delete_fieldset_$i" onclick="foo($i)">[X]</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to use javascript like this:

```
var attr_fieldset = "";
var num_fielset = 0;
var elt_fieldset = null;

// get all fieldsets
var list_fieldset = document.getElementsByClassName('fieldset_group');

for (var i = 0; i < list_fieldset.length; i++) {
    // to get one fieldset
    elt_fieldset = list_fieldset[i];
    // to get $i 
    attr_fieldset = elt_fieldset.id.split("_");
    num_fielset = attr_fieldset[1]; // (num_fielset = $i)

    // create span element
    var new_span = document.createElement("span");
    new_span.className = 'delete_fieldset_' + num_fielset;
    new_span.setAttribute('onclick', 'foo(' + num_fielset + ')');
    new_span.innerHTML = '[X]';
    // span element is the first child of the fieldset
    elt_fieldset.insertBefore(new_span, elt_fieldset.firstChild);
}
```

If you want span element after the others elements of the fieldset, replace

```
elt_fieldset.insertBefore(new_span, elt_fieldset.firstChild);
```

by

```
elt_fieldset.appendChild(new_span);
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your question.
May be this code can help you:

```
// add a Zend_Form_Element_Note (Zend 1.12)
$newtag = new Zend_Form_Element_Note('span_elt', array('value' => '<span class="delete_fieldset_'. $i .'" onclick="foo(' . $i . ')">[X]</span>'));

// Remove decorators to have only span tag
$newtag->removeDecorator('HtmlTag');
$newtag->removeDecorator('Label');

// add $newtag in your code
$this->addDisplayGroup(array_merge(array($newtag), $groupInputs), 
                       'group_'.$i, 
                       array('attribs'=>array('class'=>'fieldset_group')));
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: Zend_Form_Element_Note not found in my project :<

Comment: Sorry, If I find another solution, I'll put it. Good luck.